# Add outside array variable to foreach loop which is inside while in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I'm have time overlap check inside while loop and I would also like to display events title with results which is in another array.

Without double foreach loop I can echo $event->title; and it displays all event titles. If I put array $event which has $event->title, inside foreach which I have for overlap testing it only displays first title.

I'm newbie PHP and I'm banging my head with complete solution for a couple of days now. Any help would be awesome :(

```
while (list(,$event_row) = each($events)) {
  $event->loadEvent($event_row[0]);


  foreach ($events as $thisevent) {
    $event_array = array($event->id,$event->title);
    $conflicts = 0;
    foreach ($events as $thatevent) {
      if ($thisevent[0] === $thatevent[0]) {
        continue;
      }
      $thisevent_from = $thisevent[1];
      $thisevent_ends = $thisevent[2];
      $thatevent_from = $thatevent[1];
      $thatevent_ends = $thatevent[2];
      if ($thatevent_ends > $thisevent_from AND $thisevent_ends > $thatevent_from) {
        echo $event->title;
        $conflicts++;
        echo "Event #" . $thisevent[0] . " overlaps with Event # " . $thatevent[0] . "\n";
      }
    }
    if ($conflicts === 0) {
    echo "Event #" . $thisevent[0] . " is OK\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Without double foreach var_export($event) displays all event arrays.

```
array( 'title' => 'Event 1', 'description' => 'Event description 1', 'contact' => 'event contact 1', 'url' => '', 'link' => '', 'email' => 'event@eventemail.com', 'picture' => '', 'color' => '#009933', 'catName' => 'Events', 'catDesc' => 'General events', 'startDate' => 1432918800, 'endDate' => 1432926000, 'startDay' => 29, 'startMonth' => 5, 'startYear' => 2015, 'endDay' => 29, 'endMonth' => 5, 'endYear' => 2015, 'recurStartDate' => NULL, 'recurEndDate' => NULL, 'id' => '11', 'catId' => 1, 'status' => true, 'recType' => '', 'recInterval' => 0, 'recEndDate' => 1432850400, 'recEndType' => 0, 'recEndCount' => 1, ))
```

And var_export($events) array displays three times all arrays with id, start date and end date:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '11', 1 => 1432918800, 2 => 1432926000, ), 1 => array ( 0 => '13', 1 => 1432918800, 2 => 1432926000, ), 2 => array ( 0 => '16', 1 => 1432926000, 2 => 1432929600, ), )
```

Thank you for looking into it and giving any possible solutions hints, ideas :)

Comment: Hieu Le, if I just echo $event->title; it only displays first event Title. This is not working,

Comment: I didn't understand why that's your approach. Can you please share you `input` (`$events`) and `goals` (`desired output`) ?

Comment: $events is array with event id#, event start date, event end date. I check this event data for time overlap. I would also like to display event title with that, which is in another array $event or modify $event array so I could check for overlap and display event name, event id which overlaps or not.

Comment: I believe it can be achieved in no more than 2 loops (since you want to compare each event with the rest of existing events). Correct me if i'm missing something. **EDIT** if you need another nested loop just for printing the title - that's bad - consider using a separated loop for that purpose.

Comment: How can I use any of two arrays inside while with overlap check to echo like this for example: Event Name: Event_1 overlaps with Event Name: Event 2

Comment: Should I form new array array[] = inside foreach loop and use it outside with event name?

Comment: Exactly. it would be better.

Comment: If i form new array inside while loop $array[] = array($event->id,$event->startDate,$event->endDate); I get repeated overlap results with one added each time inside foreach. I'm totaly lost here :(